# Connecting to a mongoDB Replica Set Using Mongos On App Server

Tags: php, mongodb

We are currently facing issues with connection spikes going to our multiple Mongo Replica Sets, caused by the number of PHP-FPM children we have running. With 16 front end servers, we see spikes going all the way up to 20K connections, effectively crashing our Mongo Clusters.

We were told that the only two viable options are either to A, limit the PHP-FPM workers (something we tried, which just led to a 10GB error log of errors telling us to raise the max amount of workers) or to add a mongos server to each of our app servers, as that has connection pooling built in.

We are currently not able to figure out how we should convert our current connection string, to work with mongos.

Our connection string looks like this:

```
mongodb://admin:<password>@SG-cache1-2342.servers.xxx.com:27017,SG-cache1-2343.servers.xxx.com:27017,SG-cache1-2344.servers.xxx.com:27017/admin?replicaSet=RS-cache1-0
```

How do we convert this string into the proper format for mongos to accept. We have tried every possible combination of the string, adding and removing pieces, but they all end up failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to mongos you no longer connect to a ReplicaSet. This means the `replicaSet` option should be omitted.

Furthermore, the config servers behind mongos are already configured with full knowledge of your ReplicaSets - so you don't need to tell the mongos anything about the ReplicaSet servers.

The correct connection string would be:

```
mongodb://admin:<password>@mongos1.servers.xxx.com:27017/admin
```

You can list more then one mongos servers like this:

```
mongodb://admin:<password>@mongos1.servers.xxx.com:27017,mongos2.servers.xxx.com/admin
```